# WordPress Multisite's in subdirectory not redirecting to dashboard settings

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I am not sure what's happened but our WordPress multisite that's been in a subdirectory for the longest time now refuses to redirect to the WPMS dashboard pages. Settings, themes, plugins etc.

All the dashboard settings go to "Sorry! That page doesn't seem to exist." page.
Here's what we have tried.

- Renaming plugins folder.
- Renaming htaccess file and generating it again.
- Try changing themes but cannot get to the themes settings.
- Tried moving the site into root directory.
- Tried multiple snippets of code in the functions.php based on similar problems I have found.

This is my htacess files

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Appreciate any insight?

Comment: That `.htaccess` file doesn’t seem to be the “multisite” `.htaccess` file? And would only apply if the site was in the root directory (so after your attempts to get it working)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MrWhite - I just realised now it is the wrong htaccess file. I cannot however get to the Network settings page to get the details I need to replace the content of the htaccess because it keeps gonig to the "Sorry! That page doesn't seem to exist."

I tried replacing it with this https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#multisite but that doesn't work either